# Cleaning up a excel sheet for almost dublicate lines

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

if i have a workbook filled with data like this example below here

```
   A      B      C
1 test   edge   blue
2 test   edge   red
3 dust   daf    grey
4 dust   daf    red
```

And i want to clean this up so it says

```
   A      B      C     D
1 test   edge   blue  red
2 dust   daf    grey  red
```

anyone can help how to do this ?

Comment: Do you have access to Unix, Linux, a Unix-like system, Cygwin, or some other Unix look-alike?  If you do, the easiest solution might be to export your data to a CSV file, process it in `awk`, and then re-import it to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by A then B, then put into D1:

```
=IF(AND(A1=A2,B1=B2),C2,"")
```

Fill Down column D, then either copy and paste as values or filter out the blanks in column D. That should work if your data is all like the above.

Comment: it have to be dynamic, 10 fields cold be the same in A anb B  i dont know what the data will be before i get the sheet.

Comment: Well, in that case add more columns: E1 will have `=IF(AND(A1=A3,B1=B3),C3,"")`, and so on.

Comment: i cant do this manual the sheet might have 10000 lines, and hundred of collums, i need a macro or somthing. this must be a problem that has been solved before.